# Error 'Executing Child Request' for MVC Action when called from HttpServerUtility.Execute

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

We have recently started moving over to ASP.NET MVC 3 from webforms.  There is a PDF export utility that was written to take a page path (url) and render the html using the HttpServerUtility.Execute method.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8e2dw5s

This works fine when the url being requested is a webform, but when the it is an MVC action we just get the error "Error executing child request for /MyControllerName/MethodName.".  When debugging our IDependencyResolver class and controller constructor never get hit, so it isn't the action that is failing.

What are we doing wrong?  Is there another way to make a server side request from the current context to get the html output of an MVC action?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/102401/httpserverutility-throws-httpexception-in-attempt-to-transfer-from-httphandler-httpmodule-to-another-httphandler